# SQL Server, Daily Restore of a Test Database Environment

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2016, restore

We have MS SQL server 2016 enterprise with a single 1TB production database that we need to restore to a test environment (on another server) on a daily basis. This currently involves doing a full backup to a shared disk (generates a 130GB bak file) and a full restore every night. This works, but takes significant time (1 hour to backup and 2-3 hours to restore).

My question is, since not much really changes from day to day (gigabytes compared to rewriting a terabyte). Is there a quicker way to restore the database that we are not aware of?

I am imagining something like rolling back the test database to a point in time then applying logs to catch it up to the needed point in time?

I tried google, but could not find any articles that talked about this, so I am thinking this might not be a possible feature. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: . . You can look into replication options provided for SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I looked into this path and learned a great new many things. Unfortunately, replication comes with the downside of not being able to edit the schema in the test environment which is our main goal. I found this answer which summarizes the replication approach and recommends the Backup / Restore approach (which we are already using). But this answer is from over 6 years ago. I was hoping for a newer feature / solution. 

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54305/using-sql-snapshot-replication-to-refresh-test-databases-from-production-why-no